# For loop only runs once, despite array having a length of 9

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop

I'm running a while loop inside of a for loop. The array has a length of 9, and I have double checked the length in the program. The for loop should run for each element in the array, but instead only runs for the first element and ends. The while loop on the other hand also uses the length of the array, and runs as expected. The various 'puts' statements show this when you run the code. Why isn't the for loop running 9 times?

```
def stock_picker(stock_prices)
  differences = Array.new
  stock_prices.each do |price|
    day = 0
    puts "The for loop is starting"

    while day < stock_prices.length
      puts "The while loop is working"
      puts price
      if price < stock_prices[day]
        puts "The if statement is working"
        difference = stock_prices[day] - price
        puts difference
        differences.push(difference)
        puts differences
      end
      day += 1
    end

    puts "The for loop is ending"

  end
  puts differences
end
```

Comment: Without knowing anything about the actual data you're using it's difficult to provide meaningful input. In general, `while` loops just work. Although it's not clear why you use a while loop in one place and an `each` in the other.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for assistance.

Comment: `[17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]` is the array I'm using, and the only data involved. I worked on this late last night, so looking at it again I'm not 100% sure why I used two different kinds of loops, but I think it has something to do with the `if` comparison. I might try switching the `for loop` to another `while loop`.

Comment: There is no `for` loop in your code, or am I blind?

Comment: @scratch_pad I copied your code and called it with the array from your comment and the loop ran 9 times. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `stock_prices.each do` is a `for` loop because it runs “for” the length of the array, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: @Max idk then lol. I switched it to a `while` loop and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the best possible trade you can use the [`combination`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-combination) method to find and test possible buy/sell pairs and use `max_by` to get the best possible profit:

```
def best_theoretical_trade(prices)
  prices.combination(2).max_by do |buy,sell|
    sell - buy
  end
end

best_theoretical_trade([17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10])
# => [3, 15]
```

Where here buying at 3 and selling at 15 is the optimal strategy.

Comment: It actually is more complicated than that. `[17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]` is my array. The idea is to find the biggest difference between two numbers, **but** you have to go through the array in order, and you subtract the sequential first element from the second, larger sequential element. So in this array, 12 would be the answer (15 - 3) even though 17 - 1 gives you a larger number. Hence all the confusion. I'm probably still going about it in a rather complicated way though

Comment: If you want to find the ideal trade, given full knowledge of what has happened, then there's a different algorithm you can use. I've edited accordingly.